# Add quotes around variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to export data from SQL and import into SAS.  The address field has ',' in the middle of the string. I tried using CSV and tab delimited, but each time SAS breaks up the address field due to the ','.

I tried replacing the comma with a space using code from another question, but it did not work:

```
 update #temp2
 set STREETADDRESS_e = REPLACE(STREETADDRESS_e ,","," ")
```

I thought if I put the address string in quotes, this would solve the problem, but my code is not working:

```
 update #temp2
 set STREETADDRESS_e = ("'" + STREETADDRESS_e + "'")
```

This seems like it must be a very common problem but I have not found any working solutions...

Comment: I tagged the question as SQL Server based on syntax, if that's wrong please say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to surround the string with single-quotes you have to escape them like this:

```
update #temp2 set STREETADDRESS_e = ('''' + STREETADDRESS_e + '''')
```

or

```
update #temp2 set STREETADDRESS_e = QUOTENAME(STREETADDRESS_e,'''')
```

or if you want double-quotes

```
update #temp2 set STREETADDRESS_e = QUOTENAME(STREETADDRESS_e,'"')
```

Comment: Its odd, but the code runs fine for all three, but the result has no quotes