# Variable in sql file with single quote

Tags: sql, vertica, vsql

```
SELECT SWAP_PARTITIONS_BETWEEN_TABLES
(':SCHEMA_NAME.:TABLE_NAME',:PARTITION_KEY,:PARTITION_KEY,
':SCHEMA_NAME.:TABLE_NAME');
```

This is a vertica query in sql file
`:SCHEMA_NAME` and `:TABLE_NAME` in sql file is not getting replaced by the argument passed probably because of single quotes

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349613/add-quotes-around-variable help ?

Comment: there is only one variable in single quote 
now i need 2 variables concatenated within a single quote @KalpaWelivitigoda

Comment: Would something like, '''' + :SCHEMA_NAME + '''' + '.' + '''' + :TABLE_NAME+ '''' work? I didn't try though.

Comment: SCHEMA_NAME = abc
TABLE_NAME = xyz 
it took like 'abc'.'xyz'
i want it as 'abc.xyz'

Comment: Sry my bad, try  '''' + :SCHEMA_NAME + '.' + :TABLE_NAME+ ''''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\set source '''src_schema.src_table'''
\set target '''tgt_schema.tgt_table'''
SELECT SWAP_PARTITIONS_BETWEEN_TABLES
    (:source,:PARTITION_KEY,:PARTITION_KEY,:target);
```

If you want to use different variables for SCHEMA and TABLE, you can:

```
\set schema '''myschema'''
\set table '''mytable'''
```

And then:

```
SELECT SWAP_PARTITIONS_BETWEEN_TABLES
    (:schema||'.'||:table,:PARTITION_KEY,...);
```

Comment: this works but i have to give schema name and table name within quotes :schema||'.'||:table within quotes